# Element doesn't begin in the top left corner

Tags: css, html, header, margin

I'm making a simple website, I'm new and I'm wondering about something. I've made a header with a navbar and I want it to be the width of the screen and be all the way to the top. However, 0,0 isn't at the top left corner and I need to add a left margin with a value of -8px and a top margin of -16px. Why? Am I wrong in thinking it should be all the upper left corner to start with? Have I missed something?

```
.header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    margin: -8px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is browser specific default styles. You need to override those. You need to add additional styles

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks! I've got a lot of little details to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margins their not needed. Also you need to specify a height for the header, and its better to use hex #fff rather than rgba when dealing with simple website demands. Just makes things easier. Also specify default styles on HTML and Body.

```css
.header {
    background-color:#000;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    position: fixed;
}

html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    
</div>
```

Comment: I already have the height defined, I'm just playing around with it so it's not there and I use rgba instead of # because I'd like it to be semi transparent and it was easier. I'm just playing around tho, nothing too serious...